# UnknownHostException: while connecting to database server

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to host MySQL database on 1nd1.com. I have created a database with few tables. Getting below error while connecting to 1and1 database from java application.

When pinging from the command prompt using "ping hostname" command, getting a failure in response.

Is there any way to connect to this host from java program?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.UnknownHostException
MESSAGE: db726853948.db.1and1.com

STACKTRACE:

java.net.UnknownHostException: db726853948.db.1and1.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:246)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Contct.insertDetails(Contct.java:11)
    at Contct.main(Contct.java:28)

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

Comment: can you connect from other tools ?

Comment: Have not tried. Is there any other open source platform where MySQL database can be hosted?

Comment: try mysql query browser.you can connect to the db and test if it's working .sometimes you need to have a remort database inorder to connect from outside of server

Comment: Not able to connect using query browser as well.. getting same unknown host exception

Comment: probably your database is not a remote database have to create a remote  databse

Comment: Any other platform to achieve this?

Comment: not a platform  you need to create a remote database from cpanel.if you can't you can use rest api.basically you send some command to backhanded your server side language will handle db operations.

Answer (score 0):

**try adding your hostname to your host file**

*for example:*

```
your_host_ip(122.2.2.1)     hostname(db726853948.db.1and1.com)
```